# What is the issue with this logon trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

When I write this trigger, an error message appears when I try to logon with users other than `SYS` or `SYSTEM`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER logon_trigger
AFTER LOGON
ON DATABASE
BEGIN
 if user not in ('sys' , 'system') then
 INSERT INTO HOMEWORKU.LOGON_LOGOFF_TABLE (who, when_login,when_logoff) VALUES (user, sysdate,'null');
 end if;
END;
```

Comment: which error did you get ?

Comment: The error would be useful, but I'd imagine your `when logoff` column is a `DATE`, so the `null` value should not be quoted.

Comment: `'null'` is a string literal, not the value `null`

Answer (score 2):

If `when_logon` and `when_logoff` are both columns with data type `DATE`, then you'll get an error trying to insert a string into them - unless it happens to represent a date according to your current NLS settings, which you shouldn't rely on. So change `'null'` to an unquoted `null`.

You also need to compare the user as an uppercase value, so change `'sys'` to `'SYS`' etc.

```
if user not in ('SYS' , 'SYSTEM') then
   INSERT INTO HOMEWORKU.LOGON_LOGOFF_TABLE (who, when_login, when_logoff)
   VALUES (user, sysdate, null);
end if;
```